# Primefaces dataTable pagination together with tab view doesn't work

Tags: primefaces, pagination, tabview

I am using JSF 2.0 primefaces. I use a pagination enabled datatable inside a tab view. There are 2 tabs. The pagination works fine in the default tab. But in the other tab, on selecting the rows per page drop down value, it displays "No Records Found". I debugged and found that all the lifecycle phases are executed without hitting the load method of LazyDataModel.
Kindly help in resolving this issue as early as possible.

Comment: it will be hard to help you if you don't show any code.. I have a lazy datatable working inside a tab view (in primefaces 3.3.1), so you must have something wrong

Comment: No code = no help. We aren't psychic ;-)

Comment: Hi Damian,  Thanks for the response. Can you pls tell me if you are using two tabs with pagination in your datatable.My problem occurs only when i switch to the other tab.The default tab works perfectly fine with pagination.